# Rebind key to a different character in a specific mode?

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode

I already tried some different ways of doing this, but never got it quite right, so I put it here.

When working in buffers **using some specific modes** (`lisp-mode`, `emacs-lisp-mode`) I want to make it so a specific key inserts a different character.

In my case,

If Elisp / Lisp mode activated:

- pressing key `ö` inserts character `(`
- pressing key `ä` inserts character `)`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```lisp
(define-key
  emacs-lisp-mode-map
  "ö"
  (lambda () (interactive) (insert "(")))
(define-key
  emacs-lisp-mode-map
  "ä"
  (lambda () (interactive) (insert ")")))
```

Most major modes have an associated `*-map` variable, which holds the keyboard bindings for that mode. You can use `define-key` to add bindings to those maps.

Comment: Lambda expressions are self evaluating: you do not need to quote them.

Comment: TIL. I've updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you SO much!